# AlamofireImage Collection cell puts image in AutoPurgingImageCache after download

Tags: swift, uicollectionviewcell, alamofireimage

I have a custom `UICollectionViewCell` that gets an image with AlamofireImage (2.4). It downloads OK, but it doesn't seem to be putting in the cache.

I have a swift file with my global cache.

```
import Foundation
import Alamofire
import AlamofireImage

// AlamofireImage cache with 30 MB cache
let imageCache = AutoPurgingImageCache(
    memoryCapacity: 30 * 1024 * 1024,
    preferredMemoryUsageAfterPurge: 20 * 1024 * 1024
)
```

The collection cell looks like this. It downloads the image with `af_setImageWithURL` and in the callback puts this image in the global cache after it sets it on the cell.

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire
import AlamofireImage

    class MyCatCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var fancyImage: UIImageView!

    var imageURL: String?

    func configureCell(uri: String?) {
        imageURL = uri
        resetCell()
        loadImage()
    }

    func resetCell() {
        fancyImage.af_cancelImageRequest()
        fancyImage.image = nil
    }

    func loadImage() {
        guard imageURL != nil else {
            return
        }
        if let image = imageCache.imageWithIdentifier(imageURL!) {
            // set image from cache
            print("image from cache")
            fancyImage.image = image
        } else {
            // get image and cache it
            let url = NSURL(string: imageURL!)!
            fancyImage.af_setImageWithURL(
                url,
                placeholderImage: nil,
                filter: nil,
                imageTransition: .CrossDissolve(0.5),
                completion: { response in
                    if response.result.isSuccess {
                        print("response.result.isSuccess \(self.imageURL!)")
                        // store this in the image cache
                        imageCache.addImage(response.result.value!, withIdentifier: self.imageURL!)
                    }
                }
            )
        }
    }
}
```

The images sets in the cell, the `print("response.result.isSuccess \(self.imageURL!)")` fires (so the call back is running), but the `print("image from cache")` never fires. `imageCache.imageWithIdentifier(imageURL!)` is always `nil`. It just downloads the image again when I load this cell again using the same URL. Any idea why this isn't working?

Comment: I fixed this issue. I made the cache too small for the images that were being downloaded, so the cache was purging before I could get the reuse the image. To check the size of memory your cache is using, use **imageCache.memoryUsage**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that I only needed to make the size of the cache larger. The images I was downloading were bigger than I predicted, and the cache was filling up far too quickly, then purging.

```
// AlamofireImage cache with 60 MB cache
let imageCache = AutoPurgingImageCache(
    memoryCapacity: 60 * 1024 * 1024,
    preferredMemoryUsageAfterPurge: 20 * 1024 * 1024
)
```

You can see your cache filling up if you periodically use  **imageCache.memoryUsage**.

```
Print('Image cache size = \(imageCache.memoryUsage)')
```